# gridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener NOT working in android app

Tags: android, gridview, kotlin

My code as is follows:

```
class MySitesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val REQUEST_CODE = 3
    private val TAG = "MySitesActivity"
    lateinit var gridView: GridView
    lateinit var siteAdapter:BaseAdapter
    lateinit var sites:ArrayList<Site>
    lateinit var actionBarObject:ActionBar


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_sites)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))

        sites = ArrayList(db.appDao().getAllSites()) //From Database
        gridView = findViewById<View>(R.id.gridview) as GridView
        siteAdapter = SitesAdapter(this@MySitesActivity, sites)
        gridView.adapter = siteAdapter
        gridView.choiceMode = GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE // CAN DO IN XML
        actionBarObject = supportActionBar!!
        actionBarObject.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)


        Log.d(TAG, "* Setting MultiChoiceModeListener *")
        gridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(object : AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

            override fun onItemCheckedStateChanged(mode: ActionMode, position: Int,
                                          id: Long, checked: Boolean) {
                // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
                // such as update the title in the CAB
            }

            override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
                return false
            }

            override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
                // Inflate the menu for the CAB
                Log.d(TAG,"Inflating menu")
                mode.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, menu)
                return true
            }

            override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode) {
                // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
                // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.
            }

            override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
                // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
                // an invalidate() request
                return false
            }
        })
}


}
```

For brevity, I've removed the databse functions. The onCreate Action Mode never gets called and the Log statement never spits out the data.

My SiteAdapter Class extends the Baseadapter and the view returned is fine and it shows fine. I am not adding any listener or anything like that in my siteadapter class. Its just that on long click nothing happens. Any ideas as what could I be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: classic android, 0 documentation on that function... Does the callback "onItemCheckedStateChanged" works when selecting and deselecting an item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I've chosen the wrong mode.

GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE instead of GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL

This change solve the INITIAL problem and created a new one which I think I should post it on a seperate thread.